# Why does Hashmap throws a ConcurrentModificationException when the Hashmap size doesn't change

Tags: java, hashmap

I am studying hashmap, I can to know that when a map is iterated. hashmap internally keep a track of the hashmap size and if there is any change in the size hashmap throws ConcurrentModificationException.

Going forward with the same perspective.
Look at this piece of code

```
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("1", "1");
    myMap.put("2", "2");
    myMap.put("3", "3");
    myMap.put("4", "4");

            System.out.println("HashMap before iterator size before : " +myMap.size());
    try {
        for(String key : myMap.keySet()){
                myMap.remove("3");
                myMap.remove("4");
                myMap.put("5", "new8"); 
                myMap.put("6", "new9");
        }
    } catch(ConcurrentModificationException exception) {
        System.out.println("HashMap before iterator size after : " +myMap.size());
    }
    System.out.println("HashMap before iterator fourth : "+myMap);
```

The output of the same is :

```
HashMap before iterator size before 4
HashMap before iterator size after  4
HashMap before iterator fourth : {1=1, 2=2, 5=new8, 6=new9}
```

Why does the hashmap throw error in these case?

Comment: Read the javadoc and you will figure it out. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Comment: If you look at the code the size check is done when the or loop calls the **_hashmap.next()_** method, Not after every modification. The check is at the start of every iteration not during the iteration. Hence a change during the iteration should not be impacting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> hashmap internally keep a track of the hashmap size and if there is any change in the size hashmap throws ConcurrentModificationException

That's incorrect. For the decision whether to throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, `HashMap` keeps track of the number of modifications, not the size of the `Map`. Adding two entries and removing two entries increments the modification count by 4. Hence the exception.

The Javadoc states:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Any `put` or `remove` operations that actually add or remove an entry cause a structural modification to the `Map`, so your iterator over `myMap.keySet()` will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: If I agree that put and remove causes structural change why does this piece of code works fine?
 `
   for(Entry<String, String> key : myMap.entrySet()){
    if(key.getKey().equals("4")) {
     myMap.remove("4");      
     myMap.put("6", "new9");
    }     
   }
 `

Comment: @user2681668 If you make the structural change in the final iteration of the loop, the iterator finishes the iteration before it can detect the concurrent modification.

Comment: Exactly this means that during iteration, it checks for the structural change. how does it check for change, its the change in the size right?or there is any other code if yes Please share that would help me understand.

Comment: @user2681668 Not the size, the `modCount`. The `next()` method of the iterator compares the current modification count of the `HashMap` to the original modification count (at the time the iterator was created). If they are not equal, it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Thanks, @Eran I get this now 
The value that gets change with the modification is modCount and its compared with expectedModCount which is initially set at the beginning of the iteration of the hashmap.